# what does `program.parse(process.argv)` do in commander.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-commander, inquirerjs

I want to user `commander.js` and `inquirer.js` to ask questions and collect the answer to create a `User` instance:

```
// index.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./model/user')
const {addUser,listAllUsers,findUserByEmail,updateUser,deleteUser} = require('./model_methods/user_methods')
const { program } = require('commander');
var inquirer = require('inquirer');

// connect to DB
const db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myImportantDates', {
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true, 
});

const questions = [
    {
      type: 'input',
      name: 'email',
      message: 'user email'
    },
    {
      type: 'input',
      name: 'name',
      message: 'user name'
    },
    {
      type: 'input',
      name: 'password',
      message: 'user password'
    },
  ];



program
   .version('0.0.1')
   .description('The important dates app');

program
   .command('add')
   .alias('a')
   .description('Add a user')
   .action(
       inquirer
         .prompt(questions)
         .then( answers => {
            addUser(answers)
          })
          .catch(err =>{
            console.log(error) 
          })
   )
program.parse(process.argv);
```

When I run it with `node index.js add`, the questions array ask one question and quit:

```
@DESKTOP-5920U38:/mnt/c/Users/myApp$ node index.js add
? user email 
@DESKTOP-5920U38:/mnt/c/Users/myApp$
```

When I delete `program.parse(process.argv)`, however, everything works fine, it can return me the new `User` instance.

I check the documents: https://github.com/tj/commander.js/ 
Still have no idea what happened. Does anybody know more about this??

What I found just now is that if I put `program.parse(process.argv)` in the beginning like this in the first set up of the `program` instance:

```
program
   .version('0.0.1')
   .description('The important dates app')
   .parse(process.argv);
```

It works too. But I still don't know why the order matters.

Comment: Is that ok if I just remove the whole `program.parse(process.argv)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Node.js, `process.argv` is [an array containing the command line arguments passed when the Node.js process was launched](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv). So, `program.parse(process.argv)` parses the the command line options for arguments, which is bypassing your `inquierer.js` prompt. You can leave it out.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind checking this question too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61965755/inquirer-js-exits-the-terminal-before-asking-all-questions

Answer (score 1):

`program.parse(process.argv)` is called after setting up your program. It takes the command line arguments (`process.argv`) and parses them using your declared program, displaying errors or calling action handlers etc.

Based on your example code, an issue is the action handler takes a function parameter. e.g.

```js
.action(() => {
   // code goes here
});
```